# SVG's not inheriting values from parent

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, svg

So this seems to be a bug that just *cropped up in Chrome today* (and Firefox apparently).
I have an SVG wrapped inside a span (I've tried div's and object tags as well, it doesn't seem to matter), and that span has a specified height and width. Yesterday, the child element would size itself appropriately to the full dimensions of it's parent, as every other html element does. However, now, that **SVG element is not getting the inherited size from its parent**, and is sizing itself based off the actual size of the SVG.
Check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/theandybob/4LHeB/
The CSS:

```
.icon-small {
   width: 32px;
   height: 32px;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

And the Code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="run-import" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <path fill="#4B4B4B" d="M24,0c4.4,0,8.4,1.1,12,3.2s6.6,5.1,8.7,8.7c2.1,3.7,3.2,7.7,3.2,12s-1.1,8.4-3.2,12 c-2.1,3.7-5.1,6.6-8.7,8.7c-3.7,2.1-7.7,3.2-12,3.2c-4.4,0-8.4-1.1-12-3.2c-3.7-2.1-6.6-5.1-8.7-8.7C1.1,32.4,0,28.4,0,24 s1.1-8.4,3.2-12S8.3,5.4,12,3.2S19.6,0,24,0z M36,25.7c0.7-0.4,1-0.9,1-1.7c0-0.8-0.3-1.3-1-1.7l-17-10c-0.6-0.4-1.3-0.4-2,0 c-0.7,0.4-1,1-1,1.8v20c0,0.8,0.3,1.4,1,1.8c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.3,1,0.3c0.4,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.3L36,25.7z"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<span class="icon-small">
    <svg><use xlink:href="#run-import"></use></svg>
</span>
```

Now, this happens in Chrome (both on Windows and Mac), and Firefox, but not IE or Safari. Ideas on how to fix the issue, or where it came up from?
The only workaround I have now is to specifically set the svg size to inherit from it's parent.

**Also, throwing the version numbers out there:**
**1.** Chrome: Version 36.0.1985.125 m
**2.** Firefox: 30.0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need height and width on the `<svg>` element which you can set using CSS if you wish but which I've set using attributes.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="0" height="0">
    <symbol id="run-import" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
        <path fill="#4B4B4B" d="M24,0c4.4,0,8.4,1.1,12,3.2s6.6,5.1,8.7,8.7c2.1,3.7,3.2,7.7,3.2,12s-1.1,8.4-3.2,12 c-2.1,3.7-5.1,6.6-8.7,8.7c-3.7,2.1-7.7,3.2-12,3.2c-4.4,0-8.4-1.1-12-3.2c-3.7-2.1-6.6-5.1-8.7-8.7C1.1,32.4,0,28.4,0,24 s1.1-8.4,3.2-12S8.3,5.4,12,3.2S19.6,0,24,0z M36,25.7c0.7-0.4,1-0.9,1-1.7c0-0.8-0.3-1.3-1-1.7l-17-10c-0.6-0.4-1.3-0.4-2,0 c-0.7,0.4-1,1-1,1.8v20c0,0.8,0.3,1.4,1,1.8c0.3,0.2,0.7,0.3,1,0.3c0.4,0,0.7-0.1,1-0.3L36,25.7z"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<span class="icon-small">
    <svg width="100%" height="100%"><use xlink:href="#run-import"></use></svg>
</span>
```

Comment: That accomplishes the same thing as I mentioned before by **setting the widths and heights to be inherit**. And yes, I would make that modification to the CSS, not the element itself. The current work around is to apply the sizing:inherit on all SVG elements. I would think an issue like this would have been found before updating Chrome, but what I'm doing is completely standard. Any ideas on where it might have came up from?

Comment: In regards to your edit, previously, we could apply the viewBox to the symbol, and that would be applied to the svg inside the span. So something has changed where that is no longer the case? Before I go changing the location of the viewBox to the svg inside the span, I wanted to know what might have changed that caused this issue. I was hoping to avoid a knee-jerk reaction to try and make a "fix", only to have that fix needing to be fixed later on.

Comment: So, defining the viewBox inside of every reference of the <svg> is a royal pain, as we have hundreds of references to the symbol. My understanding (which apparently is flawed) of how the symbol works is that we can define our base qualities, and have them applied universally. Am I wrong in that?

Comment: If you want. But then you need height and width set which you could do with CSS. You do need to specify **some** sizing information on that SVG and there's no way around that.

Comment: Alright, so it appears that something has just changed with the way <svg> was *previously* receiving it's size, such that I must now explicitly say the size. Guess that's not too weird, but inconvenient. Thanks for the information, I'll go ahead and flag your response as answered.

Comment: As I said, Chrome changed fairly recently in that regard. Firefox has always required worked this way.

Comment: It must have just been the way that we've been implementing SVG's previously, as we haven't had this issue in firefox before.

Comment: Hate to bring it back up, not sure how much SVG 2.0 is used yet, but this seems contrary to what I'm seeing. From http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/struct.html#UseElement  Under the title: **If the ‘use’ element references a ‘symbol’ element**: ... If attributes ‘width’ and/or ‘height’ are not specified, the *generated ‘svg’ element will use values of '100%' for these attributes.*

Comment: That seems to confuse lots of people, the key piece of text to read is here though: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewportSpace which basically means that default properties should be ignored.