# Scale inline SVG symbol referenced with <use>

Tags: css, svg

I have an SVG logo defined as a symbol like so:

```
<svg class="SpriteSheet">
    <symbol id="icon-logo" viewBox="-12 -79.61 407.19 108.36">
        <path id="logo-upperLeft" d="M0-67.61l83.66 0 0-10 -93.66 0 0 30.92 10 0Z" transform="translate(-2 -2)"></path>
        <path id="logo-upperRight" d="M383.19-67.61l-83.66 0 0-10 93.66 0 0 30.92 -10 0Z" transform="translate(2 -2)"></path>
        <path id="logo-lowerLeft" d="M0 16.75l83.66 0 0 10 -93.66 0 0-30.92 10 0Z" transform="translate(-2 2)"></path>
        <path id="logo-lowerRight" d="M383.19 16.75l-83.66 0 0 10 93.66 0 0-30.92 -10 0Z" transform="translate(2 2)"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

This definition is included at the top of the `body` and styled with `display:none`.

Later in the document, I use the logo in this way:

```
<header class="Header">
    <h1 class="Header-headline">
        <a href="/">
            <svg class="Header-logo">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-logo"></use>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </h1>
</header>
```

I want to make the logo a certain height, with an automatic width:

```
.Header-logo {
    height: 5rem;
}
```

This results in this:
[image: svg width not scaling]

Although the height is correct (here, 1rem is 24px), the width remains the default 300px. Adding `width:auto` causes no changes. In researching this problem, I came across several possible solutions [here](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20775448/is-is-possible-to-scale-inline-svg-with-css). However, none have worked with my application: reapplying the viewBox at the point of usage cuts off a large part of the image and using an `<img>` tag is not possible because I need to retain access to the SVG's DOM for styling purposes.

I could add a hard-coded width based on the known aspect ratio of the image, but this seems to be a non-optimal solution: what if the aspect ratio of the logo changes in the future? Another option is to define `width:100%`, which does work, however, this makes the 'clickable' area of the `<a>` extend across the entire width of the header, which I would like to avoid.

Is it possible to have an automatically-sized width with a defined height when the viewBox is described in the `<symbol>` definition? Must I be relegated to using an `<img>` tag or an absolute width for the SVG element?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unfortunately it is the dimensions of the `<svg>` element that appears in your `<header>` that is important.  There is no way to inherit a `viewBox` from a child symbol reference.

You would need to copy the `viewBox` (width and height) from the symbol.

```css
.Header-logo {
    height: 5rem;
}

.Header-logo2 {
    height: 8rem;
}
```

```html
<svg class="SpriteSheet" width="0" height="0">
    <symbol id="icon-logo" viewBox="-12 -79.61 407.19 108.36">
        <path id="logo-upperLeft" d="M0-67.61l83.66 0 0-10 -93.66 0 0 30.92 10 0Z" transform="translate(-2 -2)"></path>
        <path id="logo-upperRight" d="M383.19-67.61l-83.66 0 0-10 93.66 0 0 30.92 -10 0Z" transform="translate(2 -2)"></path>
        <path id="logo-lowerLeft" d="M0 16.75l83.66 0 0 10 -93.66 0 0-30.92 10 0Z" transform="translate(-2 2)"></path>
        <path id="logo-lowerRight" d="M383.19 16.75l-83.66 0 0 10 93.66 0 0-30.92 -10 0Z" transform="translate(2 2)"></path>
    </symbol>
</svg>


<header class="Header">
    <h1 class="Header-headline">
        <a href="/">
            <svg class="Header-logo" viewBox="0 0 407.19 108.36">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-logo"></use>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </h1>
</header>

<header class="Header">
    <h1 class="Header-headline">
        <a href="/">
            <svg class="Header-logo2" viewBox="0 0 407.19 108.36">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-logo"></use>
            </svg>
        </a>
    </h1>
</header>
```

Comment: Certainly not the answer I was looking for, but at least it provides a solution! Also thank you for noting that the viewBox should start at `0 0`: my attempts with copying the viewBox used the `-12 -79.61` values and caused the image to be partially cut off.

Comment: The comment thread belonging to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24828157/600882) answer discusses some of the same issues.