# What is the correct way of <use>ing an svg?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm very confused about the `<svg>` spec as it relates to the `<use>` tag because everything I've read about it online seems to implement the tag with subtle differences.

On [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/13-svg-icon-system-use-element/) the `<svg>` is added with a `viewBox` in the `<symbol>`:

```
<svg style="display: none;">
  <defs>
    <symbol id="basketball" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <title>Basketball</title>
      <path d="M28.1,3 ... "/>
    </symbol>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

and then the `<symbol>` is plainly referenced just with the `id`:

```
<svg class="icon-basketball">
  <use xlink:href="#basketball"></use>
</svg>
```

The same is true for [this article](https://24ways.org/2014/an-overview-of-svg-sprite-creation-techniques/) and even more so in [this article](https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/) by Chris Coyier, where he explicitly points out that `<symbol>` is a better tag because you don't need a `viewBox` when referencing it.

However, referencing a symbol with a `viewBox` does not work for me, and I end up with the same error as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31053226/scale-inline-svg-symbol-referenced-with-use), which concludes that you do, in fact, need the `viewBox` when referencing a `<symbol>`. [This article](https://thatemil.com/blog/2014/04/06/intrinsic-sizing-of-svg-in-responsive-web-design/) even proposes a hack for dealing with 'intrinsic svg sizing'.

Indeed, in this short [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t5q9fohm/9/)/snippet, you can see that with a single `<symbol>`, if I add the viewbox into the `<svg>` reference it is sized correctly, without any whitespace. Yet, with the viewbox removed, there are large 'margins' at the top and bottom.

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.9.0/css/tachyons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-zap" id="zap"><path d="M13 2L3 14h9l-1 8 10-12h-9l1-8z" /></symbol></defs></svg>

<div class="tc">


 <!-- svg is always oversized -->
 <svg class="outline w3 bg-red">
  <use xlink:href="#zap"></use>
 </svg>
 
 <!-- svg is the correct size -->
 <svg class="outline w3 bg-green"  viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <use class="black" xlink:href="#zap"></use>
 </svg>
 

  
</div>
```

So what am I getting wrong about `<use>` is it the way I am defining the `<symbol>`, which currently is being generated through [svg-sprite](https://github.com/jkphl/svg-sprite) on webpack. Or has there been a recent change in the way `<svg>`s are externally referenced?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to manipulate your svg with js? Orherwise you can just load it within img tag and set dimensions with css.

Comment: The use is the same in both cases, the <svg> element that contains the <use> is not the same however, in one instance it has size information, in the other it does not.

Answer (score 3):

In the [article](https://css-tricks.com/svg-symbol-good-choice-icons/#article-header-id-1) you refer to, Chris Coyier used `symbol` to store icons in the sprite.

Each `symbol` in the sprite can have its own`viewBox`, with individual parameter values, which allows you to additionally scale and position each icon individually.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="display: none;">

  <symbol id="beaker" viewBox="214.7 0 182.6 792">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

  <symbol id="shape-icon-2" viewBox="0 26 100 48">
    <!-- <path>s and whatever other shapes in here -->  
  </symbol>

</svg>
```

In your case, when using the `<use>`, as Robert Longson wrote:

> in one instance it has size information, in the other it does not.

In the nested svg, there is also an additional scaling.
Therefore, if you want both clones to be the same size, add a svg `viewBox` to the second instance with the same parameters `viewBox =" 0 0 24 24 "`

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tachyons@4.9.0/css/tachyons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"><defs><symbol viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-zap" id="zap"><path d="M13 2L3 14h9l-1 8 10-12h-9l1-8z" /></symbol></defs></svg>

<div class="tc">


 <!-- svg is the correct size -->
 <svg class="outline w3 bg-red" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <use xlink:href="#zap"></use>
 </svg>
 
 <!-- svg is the correct size -->
 <svg class="outline w3 bg-green"  viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <use class="black" xlink:href="#zap"></use>
 </svg>
 

  
</div>
```